# How to get all values from svelte-select component when multi select is enabled

Tags: select, svelte

Hi this is an example code that works:

```
<script>
    import Select from 'svelte-select';

    const items = [
        {value: 'chocolate', label: ' Chocolate', group: 'Sweet'},
    {value: 'pizza', label: ' Pizza', group: 'Savory'},
    {value: 'cake', label: ' Cake', group: 'Sweet'},
    {value: 'cookies', label: ' Cookies', group: 'Savory'},
    {value: 'ice-cream', label: ' Ice Cream', group: 'Sweet'}
    ];

    let selectedValue = undefined;
</script>

<h1>Svelte Select Example</h1>

<h2>Favourite junk food</h2>
<Select {items} bind:selectedValue></Select>

{#if selectedValue}
    <p>Selected valued is: {selectedValue.label}</p>
{/if}
```

but when i create a multi select:

```
Select {items} isMulti={true} bind:selectedValue></Select>
```

then the result is

```
Selected valued is: undefined
```

Anyone knows the correct way to access all the selected values?
thx

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple selection, `selectedValue` is an array of objects, so it doesn't have a direct `label` property, only the array *elements* have that property.

To display the selected labels, you need to amend your code to one of the following, in order to iterate the array:

Option A: using Svelte's `#each` iterator (formatted list)

```js
{#if selectedValue}
  <p>Selected values are:</p>
  <ul>
    {#each selectedValue as sv}
      <li>{sv.label}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/if}
```

Option B: using `Array.map` and `Array.join` (comma-separated list)

```js
{#if selectedValue}
  <p>Selected values are: {selectedValue.map(s => s.label).join(', ')}</p>
{/if}
```

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/25b8cf35f5b04149965e2d79be343cd4?version=3.20.1)